# How to change props of TextInput component in a FlatList?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm a newbie in React Native.

What I'm trying to do is making a Google Maps-like app. At the `MainMap.js` screen, when we enter,the screen will immediately generate 2 search bars. The first one will have the text `"Your location"`. The second one and so on will be empty for users to type in for searching location.

But, I'm having some problems with the `FlatList` component. In my `PlaceInput` component, I use the `defaultValue`, as a prop, for the text input. And then in the `MainMap.js`, I will have a state which initially be set as `"Your Location"`, then I'll change it to `null` when the `FlatList` starts rendering from the 2nd `PlaceInput` component.

**Here's the `MainMap.js`***

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
    TouchableWithoutFeedback,
    StyleSheet,
    Keyboard,
    PermissionsAndroid,
    Platform, 
    View,
    Button,
    FlatList,
    Dimensions
} from 'react-native';

import PlaceInput from '../components/PlaceInput';

import axios from 'axios';
import PolyLine from '@mapbox/polyline';
import MapView, {Polyline, Marker} from 'react-native-maps';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

const INCREMENT = 1;
const HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

class MainMap extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={

            _userLocationDisplayed: null,
            userLatitude: 0,
            userLongitude: 0,

            numOfInput:[0,1],
            counter: 1,
        };
    };
    componentDidMount(){
        this._requestUserLocation();
    };

    // Get user current location

    // Ask user permission for current location
    // Request the Directions API from Google
    // Get the formatted_address & name from Google Places API
    // Adding a search bar
    onAddSearch(){
        this.setState((state) => ({
            counter: state.counter + INCREMENT,
            numOfInput: [...state.numOfInput, state.counter],
        }));
    };

    onChangeSearchDisplay(){
        this.setState({
            _userLocationDisplayed: null
        })
    };

    render(){

            return(
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.hideKeyboard} >
                    <View style={styles.container} >
                        <View style={{height: HEIGHT/2.5 }}>
                            <FlatList
                                data={this.state.numOfInput}
                                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item}
                                renderItem={itemData => {
                                    return(
                                        <PlaceInput
                                            id={itemData.item}
                                            onDelete={this.onDeleteSearch}
                                            showDirectionOnMap={this.showDirectionOnMap}
                                            userLatitude={userLatitude}
                                            userLongitude={userLongitude}
                                            userLocationDisplayed={this.state._userLocationDisplayed}
                                        />
                                    )
                                }}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            )
        }

    }

//}


export default MainMap;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1
    },
    map:{
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
    },
});
```

**Here's the `PlaceInput` component**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    TextInput,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    Dimensions,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Keyboard,
} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import _ from 'lodash'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'

const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;

class PlaceInput extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            ...
        }
        ...
    }

    render() {
        // console.log(this.state);
        // Code for displaying the suggestions from the Google Place API
        // Don't care about it too much :)))
        const predictions = this.state.predictions.map(prediction => {
            const { id, structured_formatting, place_id } = prediction;
            return(
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    key={id} 
                    onPress={() => this.setDestination(structured_formatting.main_text, place_id)}    
                >
                    <View style={styles.suggestion}>
                        <Text style={styles.mainText}>{structured_formatting.main_text}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.secText}>{structured_formatting.secondary_text}</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        } )

        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}} key={this.props.id}>
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center'}}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize: 8}}>{'\u25A0'}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex: 4}}>
                        <TextInput 
                            key={this.id}
                            autoCorrect={false}
                            autoCapitalize='none'
                            style={styles.inputStyle}
                            placeholder='Search your places'
                            onChangeText={(input) => {
                                this.setState({destinationInput: input});
                                this.getPlacesDebounced(input);
                            }}
                            value={this.state.destinationInput}

                            {/*What I'm trying here as mentioned*/}
                            defaultValue={this.props.userLocationDisplayed}

                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.rightCol}>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)}>
                                <Icon name='delete' size={25} style={{alignSelf: 'center'}} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                </View>
                {predictions}
            </View>
        )
    } 
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    buttonContainer:{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        height: (HEIGHT - 690),
        width: (WIDTH-48),
        marginTop: 55,
        padding: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        shadowColor: '#000000',
        elevation: 7,
        shadowRadius: 5,
        shadowOpacity: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf:'center'
    },
    inputStyle:{
        fontFamily: 'sans-serif-thin', 
        fontSize: 16, 
        color: 'black',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    suggestion:{
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        padding: 10,
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        width: (WIDTH-48),
        alignSelf: 'center'
    },
    secText:{
        color: '#777'
    },
    mainText:{
        color: '#000'
    },
    rightCol:{
        flex: 1,
        borderLeftWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#ededed',
    },
})

export default PlaceInput;
```

I'd love to hear your comments for helping me.

Also, feel free to give out other ways too since I think my way isn't optimized enough. And I'm building this for production too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take advantage of Drew Reese's answer but It doesn't work

I found out why it doesn't work because of the `value` prop, whose value is set by `this.state.destinationInput` which is " " in the state in the constructor. I again use Drew's way in the `value` prop instead, and it works

```
                     <TextInput 
                        key={this.id}
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        autoCapitalize='none'
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        placeholder='Search your places'
                        onChangeText={(input) => {
                            this.setState({destinationInput: input});
                            this.getPlacesDebounced(input);
                        }}
                        value={this.props.displayDefaultValue ? this.props.defaultValue : this.state.destinationInput}
                    />
```

BIG thanks to Drew Reese

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking how to conditionally set a prop value based upon where it is in the flatlist data. Basically you want the first `PlaceInput` component to have a displayed "entered" text value of "Your Location" and the rest to have nothing.

Update API of `PlaceInput` to take in another prop to indicate displaying a default value or not.

PlaceInput.js

```
...
<TextInput 
  key={this.id}
  autoCorrect={false}
  autoCapitalize='none'
  style={styles.inputStyle}
  placeholder='Search your places'
  onChangeText={(input) => {
    this.setState({destinationInput: input});
    this.getPlacesDebounced(input);
  }}
  value={this.state.destinationInput}
  defaultValue={this.props.displayDefaultValue ? this.props.defaultValue : null}
/>
...
```

And pass in whether or not any specific `PlaceInput` should display it or not. Since you want ***only*** the first to display and the rest to not, using the array index is a good place to start. Here we can leverage the fact that in *javascript* `0` is a falsey value, while all other numbers are truthy. Using `!index` then `!0` is `true`  while `!1`, `!2`, etc, are all `false`.

MainMap.js

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.numOfInput}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item}
  renderItem={({ index, item }) => {
    return(
      <PlaceInput
        id={item}
        defaultValue="Your Location"
        displayDefaultValue={!index} // index 0 is falsey, all others truthy
        onDelete={this.onDeleteSearch}
        showDirectionOnMap={this.showDirectionOnMap}
        userLatitude={userLatitude}
        userLongitude={userLongitude}
        userLocationDisplayed={this.state._userLocationDisplayed}
      />
    )
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Can I ask why do we use ```({index, item})``` instead of ```(index, item)```? Since my ```data```  prop for the FlatList is just an array of ascending numbers.

Comment: And I tried to do your way Drew, but it doesn't work. It confused me a lot since I tried to put ```defaultValue = "Your location"``` right in the ```TextInput``` in ```PlaceInput```, it even doesn't show ```"Your location"```

Comment: Ahh. I know why It doesn't work. It's because of the ```value``` prop, whose value is set by ```this.state.destinationInput``` which is ```" "``` in the state in the ```constructor```. I use your way in the ```value``` prop instead, and it works !Thank you very much for the useful help @Drew

Comment: @Marwin Use `({ index, item })` because *that* is the signature of the [`renderItem`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#renderitem) callback. `renderItem` is a callback function that is passed a single object parameter with `item`, `index`, and `separators` properties. In my example I was simply taking advantage of the index. You can use object destructuring to "unpack" and access them directly in the function signature. Also, glad to help.